# Should this question about development tools be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I was going through the triage review and came across [What are Real-Time SW Development tools? And some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480314/what-are-real-time-sw-development-tools-and-some-examples). I felt it should be closed, but I wasn't sure what reason to use. I skipped it as I didn't want to apply an incorrect close reason. I would think this would fall under to broad or primarily opinion based but I just don't know.

Should this question be closed and if so what should it be closed as?

Comment: I think its an answerable question. It *might* be a better fit on Programmers.SE, but not terrible here.

Comment: *Too broad* does nicely (because they ask for examples and are unclear in what they are asking about), closed it as such.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Have to disagree here. The answer would basically just be a definition of the term (one I don't actually know). How is that too broad? Argue off-topic if you must, but its a pretty narrow question.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: the *and examples* part shows the user wants to know much more about the tools than a good focused question would ask for.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: if you want to tune it up and make it an actual question (with some show of research, there isn't any there at all) be my guest. But that is a very low quality question as it stands.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The research part is the tough one, I'm assuming the answer will show up in a google search :). I might give it a go though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Surprisingly nothing on Google. Perhaps the OP is just confused. I did reword it to fit my interpretation of the question though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: that's already better; perhaps ask the confused OP as to where they saw that.  A link to an existing job ad would speak louder.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for closing it as it was.  It left a bad taste in my mouth and I just couldn't figure out what the taste was.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You did an nice job making the question better.  As it is now I have voted to reopen.

Comment: There's going to be a lot of opinion in any answers, unless it is an exact term. I hope the clarification comes before the reopens reach five.

Comment: @MartijnPieters job description link was posted, it does contain the term in question.

Comment: I might have viewed "and some examples" as a request for off site resources.

Comment: Please consider: [What languages are used for real time systems programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697916/what-languages-are-used-for-real-time-systems-programming). I suspect that "real-time software development tools" probably refers to those tools (e.g., IDEs) that are used to write code in languages designed for use with real-time systems. (I have added a similar comment on [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31480314/1497596).)

Comment: ...at TWP, it would be closed in a heartbeat: [Questions seeking advice on **company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies**...](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2694/168) Not surprising that site specialising on questions of the kind knows better how to categorize typical bad questions of that kind

Answer (score 4):

The initial question was both unclear and too broad and really deserved to be closed. After George's edits, it is now a correct one. But is has another problem: it is really a niche question. Some times ago, I also voted to close a question about a real-time system without noticing that particularity, and it was closed almost immediately. Then the OP explained that the reasons for closing were wrong, and the question was re-opened - more or less like this one, but it took more time as moderators have more powers ;-)

But as it looks that there are very few real-time specialists around, it never got a correct answer.

My conclusion is that questions about real-time systems are ofter hard to understand to users not being used to those systems and may be closed for lack of understanding without being terrible, which is a pity. But anyway, they have little chance to get a good answer...